# Google-Talk invisibility

Tags: xmpp, invisible, google-talk

I was trying to create an XMPP and a Jabber chat-program.

I was unable to set chat state to 'Invisible'.
I would love to hear from users experience if this is possible and how they do that.
I don't mind to use any .NET assembly for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XEP-0126](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0126.html) specifies the best practices for implementing invisibility of presence.